# for loop iterates into a NoneType only during a __str__ statement?

Tags: python, iterator

So I'm working in Python trying to create a `ShapeSet` instance that contains a list of `Shape` instances and I need it to print out the list of `Shape` instances.

I can use the for loop in other parts of the code without running into an error. However, when I attempt a `print` statement it prints out the whole list and at the end results in error:
`__str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)`

I don't understand why it fails to understand to stop at the end of the list here. (At least that's what I think it's doing).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class ShapeSet:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize any needed variables
        """
        self.collect = []
        self.place = None

    def __iter__(self):
        """
        Return an iterator that allows you to iterate over the set of
        shapes, one shape at a time
        """
        self.place = 0
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.place >= len(self.collect):
            raise StopIteration
        self.place = self.place + 1
        return self.collect[self.place-1]

    def addShape(self, sh):
        """
        Add shape sh to the set; no two shapes in the set may be
        identical
        sh: shape to be added
        """
        s_count = 0
        c_count = 0
        t_count = 0
        self.collect.append(sh)
        for i in self.collect:
            if type(sh) == Square and type(i) == Square:
                if sh.side == i.side:
                    s_count = s_count + 1
                if s_count == 2:
                    self.collect.remove(sh)
                    print('already there')
            if type(sh) == Circle and type(i) == Circle:
                if sh.radius == i.radius:
                    c_count = c_count + 1
                if c_count == 2:
                    self.collect.remove(sh)
                    print('already there')
            if type(sh) == Triangle and type(i) == Triangle:
                if sh.base == i.base and sh.height == i.height:
                    t_count = t_count + 1
                if t_count == 2:
                    self.collect.remove(sh)
                    print('already there')

    def __str__(self):
        """
        Return the string representation for a set, which consists of
        the string representation of each shape, categorized by type
        (circles, then squares, then triangles)
        """
        for i in self.collect:
            if type(i) == Square:
                print ('Square with measurements ' +  str(i.side))
            if type(i) == Circle:
                print ('Circle with measurements ' + str(i.radius))
            if type(i) == Triangle:
                print ('Triangle with measurements, base/height ' + str(i.base)+ ' ' + str(i.height))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the docstring in your `__str__` function. You're suppose to "return the string representation" not `print` it. Since there is no `return` statement in the `__str__` function, it returns `None`, which `print` chokes on.

Instead, actually `return` the desired string, and let the external `print` call display it:

```
def __str__(self):
    """
    Return the string representation for a set, which consists of
    the string representation of each shape, categorized by type
    (circles, then squares, then triangles)
    """
    strings = []
    for i in self.collect:
        if type(i) == Square:
             strings.append('Square with measurements ' +  str(i.side))
        if type(i) == Circle:
            strings.append('Circle with measurements ' + str(i.radius))
        if type(i) == Triangle:
            strings.append('Triangle with measurements, base/height ' + str(i.base)+ ' ' + str(i.height))
    return '\n'.join(strings)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of it like a function that just prints out my shapeset, instead of a __str__.

Answer (score 3):

You wrote

```
def __str__(self):
    """
    **Return** the string representation for a set, which consists of
    the string representation of each shape, categorized by type
    (circles, then squares, then triangles)
    """
```

but you don't `return` anything - you just print stuff.

Put a appropriate `__str__` method on all your classes:

```
class Square:

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Square with measurements ' +  str(i.side)

class Circle:

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Circle with measurements ' + str(i.radius)

# and so on
```

and a representation for your `ShapeSet`:

```
class ShapeSet:

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(str(x) for x in self.collect)
```

Now you can `print(some_shapeset)` as well as `print(some_circle)`.

Comment: Thank you! And very good code too, I was wondering how I was going to get the ShapeSet function to return the correct information. I'll be studying your code. Once again thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could also do whatever you like within the **str** method, itterate, print outputs, more logic, etc, as long as at the end, you return a string i.e. return "" just to satisfy the requirement.

In Your case:

```
def __str__(self):
    """
    Return the string representation for a set, which consists of
    the string representation of each shape, categorized by type
    (circles, then squares, then triangles)
    """
    for i in self.collect:
        if type(i) == Square:
            print ('Square with measurements ' +  str(i.side))
        if type(i) == Circle:
            print ('Circle with measurements ' + str(i.radius))
        if type(i) == Triangle:
            print ('Triangle with measurements, base/height ' + str(i.base)+ ' ' + str(i.height))
    return ""
```